# Division for list length gives back 0 Python

Tags: python, list, sage

I wrote the following Sage code:

```
def Frequences(cad) :
    p = {}
    lcad = list(cad)
    Car = sorted(list(dict.fromkeys(lcad)))

    for i in lcad :
        p[i] = lcad.count(i)
    p1 = list(p.values())

    Prob = []
    for i in p1 :
        Prob.append(i/len(lcad))

    print(Prob)
    return Car
```

Where "Prob" is a list of integers.
I use the 'append' function to divide every element for the list's length, but if I divide for "len(lcad)" it gives me 0, while if I divide for an integer (for example 2) it gives me back 1/2.
How can I solve?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a problem with the display on SO, but your code isn't indented properly

Comment: Including a piece of repeatable code, with just enough data, might clear this up.

Comment: Hang on. "Where "Prob" is a list of integers" → are you using a Python version older than 3?

Comment: @usr2564301 I'm coding on Sage

Comment: At the very least, provide an example of the argument you pass to `Frequencies` when you call it.

Comment: To `Frequencies` I pass a string. Then it transform the string in a list, count the occurency of every element and put it in Prob. I need to divide every element of Prob by the length of `lcad` which is the list, but it gives me back 0 while if I print `lcad` as an integer it gives me the exact length of the list

Comment: @chepner that's it

Comment: So something like `Frequencies("1234")`? An example is worth far more than a description.

Comment: @chepner for example, I write `Frequencies('bee')`.
The list `Prob` should be: `[1/3, 2/3]`.
If I divide for 3, everything goes right.
If I divide for `len(lcad)`, it gives 0.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you do not necessarily store it as an integer value, but as s float.

Comment: This is Python. You don't get to choose how to store. (Nor do you *need* to.)